# Split the result of a DataFrame.groupby function into 2 or more parts

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to split a very large dataframe into smaller chunks, but the split has to be done so instances of certain columns aren't split. I know I can use group by to group values together, but how can I split the dataframe afterwards?

example the below `df`:

```
AID    VID    FID
1      A      X
1      B      Y
1      B      Z
1      A      W
1      A      Y
2      C      X
3      C      Z
3      C      W
```

I group the df on the two columns `AID`, `VID` and end up with 4 groups:

```
1,A
1,B
2,C
3,C
```

I wan't to split the dataframe into 2 so I have roughly half the rows in each dataframe.

```
df1:

AID    VID    FID
1      A      X
1      B      Y
1      B      Z
1      A      W
1      A      Y

df2:
AID    VID    FID
2      C      X
3      C      Z
3      C      W
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's just about splitting the dataframe into two equal parts(half the number of rows in each) then you can use

```
df1,df2 = df[:len(df)/2],df[len(df)/2:]
len(df1),len(df2)
```